# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}e^{i\alpha x}d\alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, branch-cuts

I need to evaluate the Fourier inverse integral

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}e^{i\alpha x}d\alpha \tag*{}$

which arose while solving a PDE.

Here, $H>0,x\in\mathbb{R},y\in[0,H]$. The domain of $\omega$ was not given in the original problem, but I am going to assume $\omega>0$ for simplicity.

The problem asks us to introduce proper branch cuts for the square root function before evaluating the integral.

For reference, [this is the original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqUMb.jpg). My attempt up until I get the integral is also shown in the link.

**My Attempt**

The branch points of the square root functions are at $\alpha =\pm\omega$. So, I considered the following branch cuts and contours.

[image]

(Here $\omega$ has an absolute value, but you can ignore it and assume $|\omega|=\omega$)

We, firstly, need to find the poles of the integrand in the upper half-plane. Those are given by the equation

$H\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}=n\pi i\tag*{}$

Solving this, we obtain

$\displaystyle \alpha =\pm\sqrt{\omega^2-\frac{n^2\pi^2}{H^2}}\tag*{} $

where $n=0,1,2,\cdots$.

The problem is that some of those poles are on the branch cuts depending on the parameters. I have been told this is not permissible, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Edit: The statement that "some of those poles are on the branch cuts" is not correct. It is on the real axis but between $[-\omega,\omega]$.

Edit2: *Tables of Fourier Transforms and Fourier Transforms of Distributions* by Fritz Oberhettinger states(p37,7.48) that if $a<b$, we have

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh{(a\sqrt{k^2+x^2}})}{\sinh{(b\sqrt{k^2+x^2}})}\cos{xy}dx = -\pi b^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nc_n\sin{(ac_n)}v_n^{-1}e^{-yv_n}$

where $c_n=n\pi/b$, $v_n = (k^2+c_n^2)^{1/2}$. I would guess our integral would have a similar form.

Comment: How do you define the integrand (and specifically the square roots) for $|\alpha|<\omega$?

Comment: @Stefan I am assuming that is part of the question since the problem asks I need to insert a proper branch cut.  In my answer I have defined $\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}=r_1r_2e^{i \frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}$ where $r_i,\theta_i$ are defined by the local coordinates $z+\omega =r_1e^{i\theta_1}$,$z-\omega=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ with $\theta_1,\theta_2$ restricted by branch cuts above, that is, $-\pi<\theta_1<\pi$ and $0<\theta_2<2\pi$.

Comment: Is an infinite sum better than the integral?

Comment: There is no branch cut on $(-\omega,\omega)$, it cancels out. There may, however, be simple poles, depending on $\omega H$, more precisely for $$\omega H > \pi\,. $$ For the derivation you can assume $\omega H<\pi$ though, which puts all the poles on the imaginary axis. In that case you see that, upon decomposing $$e^{i\alpha x} = \cos(\alpha x) + i\sin(\alpha x) \, ,$$
the $\sin$ contribution vanishes, since it is odd and so you arrive at the series expansion you gave.

Comment: @Diger Thanks for your comment. I am not sure what kind of contour I should use to apply the residue theorem. I tried semicircle shown in the question but I failed to prove that the integral on semicircle converges to zero.

Comment: @Diger Here I meant the larger semicircle.

Comment: So, I guess you know how to apply the residue theorem and as much as your actual question is concerned, you want to see a proof about the vanishing of the semi-circle integral?

Comment: @Diger I guess yes, In the class we have been told that if we have poles on the real axis, then we can pretend $\omega$ has small positive imaginary parts and kick them out from the real axis. So I think if we could prove that the semicircle vanishes, we can find the series expression similar to the one in the question.

Comment: Right, have you tried to use the standard absolute value estimate for the contour $\alpha=Re^{it}$?

Comment: @Diger Yes, so if $R\to \infty$, $\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$ is asymptotically equal to $Re^{it}$, so our integrand would look like $\frac{\sinh{Rye^{it}}}{\sinh{RHe^{it}}}e^{ixR\cos{t}}e^{-xR\sin{t}}iRe^{it}dt $. If $x>0$ this goes to zero but if $x\leq 0$ it doesn't, so not sure what to do.

Comment: Replacing the square-root with $Re^{it}$ for $R\rightarrow \infty$ is fine. How are you certain that it vanishes for $x>0$? Can you formally prove it? The case $x<0$ is no different; just close it in the lower half-plane i.e. $t\in(\pi,2\pi)$.

Comment: @Diger I am actually not sure about that, I thought so because $Re^{-xR\cos{t}}\to 0$ but I am having trouble finding a dominating function to apply the dominated convergence theorem. (Justification of exchanging limit and integral is outside of my course though)

Comment: Set $z=x+iy$ and $0<t<1$, then $$\left| \frac{\sinh(tz)}{\sinh(z)}\right| = \sqrt{\frac{\cosh^2(tx)-\cos^2(ty)}{\cosh^2(x)-\cos^2(y)}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2(tx)+\sin^2(ty)}{\sinh^2(x)+\sin^2(y)}} \, .$$
Neither $e^{-xR\cos(t)}$ nor $e^{-xR\sin(t)}$ goes to $0$ in the limit for all $t\in [0,\pi]$. For example $$\int_0^\pi {\rm d}t \, R\,e^{-xR\sin(t)}$$ does not vanish.

Comment: @Diger Yes, I see that, so if we take the absolute value of the integrand it is bounded by $\frac{\cosh{Ry\cos{t}}}{\sinh{RH\cos{t}}}Re^{-xR\sin{\theta}}$. My understanding is that I need to prove that the integral of this goes to zero, Direct calculation does not seem possible, so I am not sure what the next step is.

Comment: I just deleted the previous comment, to extent it. Maybe you introduce just another inequality $$\sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2(tx)+\sin^2(ty)}{\sinh^2(x)+\sin^2(y)}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2(tx)+1}{\sinh^2(x)+0}} = \frac{\cosh(tx)}{\sinh(x)} \leq 2e^{tx-x} \, ,$$ for sufficiently large $x$. Now you have an integral, simple enough, in terms of $\theta$. Notice the symmetry about $\theta=\pi/2$, so you only need to consider $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$. Furthermore you can split the integral at $\theta=\pi/4$ and estimate each integral by itsself.

Comment: You may want to do the splitting at $\theta=\pi/4$ before you do the estimation, otherwise you end up with $0$ in the denominator :-) Above estimate is fine for $\theta\in(0,\pi/4)$, but you need to go back to the LHS of my previous comment, to properly estimate on $\theta\in(\pi/4,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the branch cut $(-\infty,0)$ of the square-root transfers to $\sinh(\sqrt{z})$, the integral actually does not possess any branch cut. The only branch-cut that could possibly occur, would be $(-\omega,\omega)$. However, the phase-jump cancels out in ratio: if for some $\Re(\alpha) \in (-\omega,\omega)$, $\alpha$ goes from the upper half-plane into the lower half-plane, $\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$ changes from being of the form $\pm i\cdot r$ to $\mp i\cdot r$, for some real number $r$, but $$\sinh(\pm i r)=\pm i \sin(r) \, .$$
Hence, no jump i.e. no branch-cut.

Since you already know how to obtain the result from the residue theorem, here is a proof that shows the vanishing of the semicircle. However, you do not need to use a semi-circle. You can also take a box of side-length $R$, which turns out to be a bit easier.

Writing $\alpha=r+is$, the contour for $x>0$ is
$$C_R=\{r=R,s\in(0,R)\} \cup\{r\in(R,-R),s=R\} \cup \{r=-R,s=(R,0)\} \, ,$$
from which we'll find
$$\left|\int_{C_R}\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)} \, e^{i\alpha x} \, d\alpha \right| \leq \int_{0}^R \left|\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{(R+is)^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{(R+is)^2-\omega^2}\right)} \right| \, e^{-xs} \, ds \\
+\int_{-R}^{R} \left|\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{(r+iR)^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{(r+iR)^2-\omega^2}\right)} \right| \, e^{-xR} \, dr + \int_{0}^R \left|\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{(-R+is)^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{(-R+is)^2-\omega^2}\right)} \right| \, e^{-xs} \, ds \\
= I_1 + I_2 + I_3 \, .$$
Now we notice:

1. The first and third integral are the same, since the arguments of the absolute value function are just complex-conjugate to each other.
2. As $|R+is|$ is large, i.e.
   $$\sqrt{(R+is)^2-\omega^2} = R + is + O\left( \frac{1}{|R+is|} \right)$$
   we can remove the square-root. The error made will be small compared to the main term, since $$\sinh(R+is+\epsilon) = \sinh(R+is) \left\{ \cosh(\epsilon) + \coth(R+is) \sinh(\epsilon) \right\} \\
   = \sinh(R+is) \left\{1+O(\epsilon)\right\}$$
   where $\epsilon=O\left(|R+is|^{-1}\right)$ is small.
3. The following identity holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$\left| \sinh\left(x+iy\right) \right|^2 = \sinh^2(x) + \sin^2(y) \, .$$
4. In estimating the contribution along the box, we need to avoid the poles of $1/\sinh$ on the imaginary axis at $in\pi$. As $R\rightarrow \infty$, we can assume $HR=(n+1/2)\pi$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for integers $n$.

Using these observations, we can estimate as follows:
$$I_1 \leq \int_0^R \sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2(yR)+\sin^2(ys)}{\sinh^2(HR)+\sin^2(Hs)}} \, e^{-xs} \, {\rm d}s \leq \int_0^R {\frac{\cosh(yR)}{\sinh(HR)}} \, e^{-xs} \, {\rm d}s \leq \frac{\cosh(yR)}{\sinh(HR)} \frac{1}{x} \\
I_2 \leq \int_{-R}^R \sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2(yr)+\sin^2(yR)}{\sinh^2(Hr)+\sin^2(HR)}} \, e^{-xR} \, {\rm d}r \leq \int_{-R}^R {\frac{\cosh(yr)}{\cosh(Hr)}} \, e^{-xR} \, {\rm d}r \leq 2R e^{-xR} \, .$$

Comment: How did you get $\cos{(Hr)}$ in the denominator on inequality for $I_2$?

Comment: Nevermind, due to the assumption $RH=(n+1/2)\pi$, right?

Comment: Yes, you can make that assumption. But even if you don't, then $$\sinh^2(Hr)+\sin^2(HR) = \cosh^2(Hr) \left(1 - \frac{\cos^2(HR)}{\cosh^2(Hr)} \right) \\ \geq \cosh^2(Hr) \left(1-\cos^2(HR)\right) = \cosh^2(Hr) \sin^2(HR) \, .$$ Obviously, you just need to avoid the poles.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I will provide the complete solution I can imagine.

We calculate the integral for $x>0$. The case $x<0$ can be solved with a similar method.

We firstly note that the poles of the integrand are located at $\alpha =\pm p_n(n=1,2,3\cdots)$ where $p_n= \sqrt{\omega^2-\frac{n^2\pi^2}{H^2}}$. If $\omega H<\pi$ then every pole is on the imaginary axis, but if $\omega H>\pi$ then some poles are on the real axis. We consider the case $\omega H<\pi$. Otherwise we can consider the contour going around the poles.

The integrand has a branch point at $\alpha=\pm \omega$, so we define a branch cut on a real axis going away from the branch points. We then consider the following rectangle contour as @Diger advises.

[image]

Here, $\epsilon>0$ is an arbitrarily small number, and $R$ is an arbitrarily large number (However, we take $R$ so that rectangle does not have poles on it). For $x>0$ we take the rectangle in the upper half-plane. For $x<0$ we use the dotted rectangle.

We now calculate the residues of the poles at $\alpha=p_n$.  We note that the residue of $\frac{N(z)}{D(z)}$ at $z=z_0$ is $\frac{N(z_0)}{D'(z_0)}$($N, D$ is a function that is analytic near $z=z_0$ and $D$ has a simple zero at $z=z_0$). Applying the formula, we obtain that the residue at $\alpha=p_n$ is

$\displaystyle -H^{-1}(-1)^n c_n\sin{(yc_n)}p_n^{-1}e^{ip_nx}\tag*{}$

Here, $c_n=n\pi /H$. Note that we have a similar formula in the question.

Thus, by the residue theorem, the integral on the rectangle is

$\displaystyle -2\pi iH^{-1}\sum_{|p_n|<R}(-1)^n c_n\sin{(yc_n)}p_n^{-1}e^{ip_nx}\tag*{}$

Now we calculate integrals on each contour. The integrals on $C_1, C_2$ and $C_3$ goes to $0$ as $R\to\infty$, as @Diger proves. So we need to prove that the integral on $E_1$ and $E_2$ goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

On $E_1$, we have $\alpha =-\omega +\epsilon e^{i\theta}(\theta:\pi\to 0)$. Thus, $d\alpha =i\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ and $K=(-2\omega \epsilon e^{i\theta}+\epsilon^2 e^{2i\theta})^{1/2} = -2\omega \epsilon e^{i\theta}+O(\epsilon^2)$. Thus, we have $K=-2\omega \epsilon \cos{\theta}-2i\omega \epsilon\sin{\theta}$.

We have $|\sinh(x+yi)|^2=\sinh^2(x)+\sin^2(y)$ and $\frac{4}{\pi^2}c^2\leq \sin^2{c}\leq c^2\leq \sinh^2{c}$ for small $c$, so

[image]
(Forgive the image; I got too lazy)

The integral on $E_2$ also goes to zero by the same method. Thus, by taking $\epsilon\to 0, R\to\infty$, we have

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}e^{i\alpha x}d\alpha = \displaystyle -2\pi iH^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n c_n\sin{(yc_n)}p_n^{-1}e^{ip_nx}\tag*{}$

If $\omega H<\pi$, every $p_n$ is imaginary number, so we can write $p_n=iv_n$ where $v_n=\sqrt{n^2\pi^2/H^2-\omega^2}$. Thus we have

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh\left(y\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}{\sinh\left(H\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega^2}\right)}e^{i\alpha x}d\alpha = \displaystyle -2\pi H^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n c_n\sin{(yc_n)}v_n^{-1}e^{-xv_n}\tag*{}$

which gives the exact same formula like the one in the question.